# Помогите перенести написанное на XAML, в code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Нужна помощь в следующем. У меня в окне есть интерфейс для работы с графикой. Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии этот элемент подсвечивался. Реализовать это с помощью XAMl получилось, но когда переношу в code behind, у меня binding не реагирует на обновление, и соответственно не подсвечивается элемент. 
Вот код в XAML(он работает как надо):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <buildingDemo:BoundsConverter x:Key="BoundsConverter"></buildingDemo:BoundsConverter>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="Container">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.61*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <h:HelixViewport3D x:Name="hVp3D" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True" MouseDown="UIElement_OnMouseDown" Background="LightGray" IsHeadLightEnabled="True" ZoomAroundMouseDownPoint="True" RotateAroundMouseDownPoint="True">
        <h:BoundingBoxVisual3D BoundingBox="{Binding SelectedObject, Converter={StaticResource BoundsConverter}}" Diameter="0.2"/>
    </h:HelixViewport3D>
    <pt:PropertyGrid Grid.Column="1" SelectedObject="{Binding SelectedObject}" TabVisibility="Collapsed" Margin="4" RequiredAttribute="{x:Type componentModel:BrowsableAttribute}"/>
</Grid>
```

Элемент который должен выделять выбранный объект - это BoundingBoxVisual3D.
Вот code behind:

```
private BoundingBoxVisual3D createBinding()
{
    BoundingBoxVisual3D boundBox = new BoundingBoxVisual3D();
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.Source = viewModel.SelectedObject;
    binding.Converter = new BoundsConverter();
    binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    boundBox.Diameter = 0.2;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(boundBox, BoundingBoxVisual3D.BoundingBoxProperty, binding);
    return boundBox;
}
```

Здесь при нажатии на какой-либо объект, в viewModel.SelectedObject помещается этот объект.
Все остальное отлично создавалось и в коде, но из-за того что эта часть не получилась - пришлось перейти в XAML. Теперь вышло ужасно - часть реализации в XAML, часть в коде, хочется все сгрести в одну кучу. Спасибо.

Comment: `хочется все сгрести в одну кучу` - а вот это очень плохой подход. Посмотрите в сторону MVVM, там вовсе все разделено на свои слои, на свои объекты.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Вы наверное не правильно меня поняли, а точнее я не так выразился. Имелось ввиду что сейчас половина объектов сцены у меня описано в коде, а половина в XAML, и вот это я бы хотел объединить и все поместить в код.

Comment: Ну вы же понимаете, что это не правильно как то? Не зря же XAML существует, а вы хотите попросту с него все перенести в код. Это вам не даст нечего толкового, лишь головную боль в дальнейшей поддержке проекта! Очень сильно советую вам часть интерфейса (View) оставить в XAML и при помощи привязок взаимодействовать с остальным кодом.

Comment: `Binding SelectedObject` — это не равносильно `binding.Source = viewModel.SelectedObject;`. `Binding SelectedObject` — это `new Binding("SelectedObject");`